# How to change background color of vs code menu

Tags: visual-studio-code

My visual studio code looks like below

[image]

You can see that background color of popped up menu is white so that I can't see any menu item. How to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "menu.background": "#ff0000"
}
```

in your settings.

When within the `workbench.colorCustomizations` option, just type `menu` and you will see a bunch of menu-related options to colorize.